# WHat causing CkEditor to add a toolbar in middle of the page

Tags: javascript, textarea, ckeditor, toolbar

I am not understanding what causing spaceShared plugin to add a new toolbar in the middle of the textarea.

Recently I added the plugin SharedSpaces to my CkEditor and I took the code from the samples that I got from the SharedSpaces, Even then I am getting the toolbar in between the textareas.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="topSpace">
    </div>
    <form action="sample_posteddata.php" id="editorsForm" method="post">
        <p>
                    <label for="editor1">
                        Editor 1 (uses the shared toolbar and elements path):</label>
                    <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
                    <label for="editor2">
                        Editor 2 (uses the shared toolbar and elements path):</label>
                    <textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="3">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
                    <label for="editor3">
                        Editor 3 (uses the shared toolbar only):</label>
                    <textarea cols="80" id="editor3" name="editor3" rows="3">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
                    <label for="editor4">
                        Editor 4 (no shared spaces):</label>
                    <textarea cols="80" id="editor4" name="editor4" rows="3">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <div id="bottomSpace">
    </div
```

Javascript part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

        // Create all editor instances at the end of the page, so we are sure
        // that the "bottomSpace" div is available in the DOM (IE issue).

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
            {
                sharedSpaces :
                {
                    top : 'topSpace',
                    bottom : 'bottomSpace'
                },

                // Removes the maximize plugin as it's not usable
                // in a shared toolbar.
                // Removes the resizer as it's not usable in a
                // shared elements path.
                removePlugins : 'maximize'
            } );

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2',
            {
                sharedSpaces :
                {
                    top : 'topSpace',
                    bottom : 'bottomSpace'
                },

                // Removes the maximize plugin as it's not usable
                // in a shared toolbar.
                // Removes the resizer as it's not usable in a
                // shared elements path.
                removePlugins : 'maximize'
            } );

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3',
            {
                sharedSpaces :
                {
                    top : 'topSpace',
                    bottom : 'bottomSpace'
                },

                // Removes the maximize plugin as it's not usable
                // in a shared toolbar.
                removePlugins : 'maximize, elementspath',

            } );

        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor4' );
    //]]>
    </script>
```

How can I fix it or remove the unwanted toolbar that is appearing

Comment: Mind setting up a JSFiddle or the like?

Comment: I will do it now and update it

Comment: I have it on http://t.yellowandred.in/sample/plugins/ckeditor_spaceshared/index.html, 
Issue 1: undefined toolbar in Editor 2 part,
Issue 2: cursor shifts to last part and not able to edit any part of the first three editors

code taken from sample.html got from ckeditor plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in the sample you attached:

1. Some poor-quality 3rd party plugins are throwing errors and use `console.log` (sic!). From what I see this is some source code editor and most likely word count plugins. Remove them from your build.
2. As in the [sharedspace sample](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.1.2/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html) you need to remove the `floatingspace` plugin which conflicts with `sharedspace`.

After this everything should be ok.

Comment: I am rebuilding the ckeditor removing few plugins. Let me see what happens next. Thanks Reinmar

Comment: I rebuilt the Ckeditor using builder. I also downloaded all three versions and installed them locally, none of them have problem before ths [tag:spaceshared] plugin is installed. Right after I update the SpaceShared plugin the two bugs appears. I didnot find [tag:floatingspace] plugin

Comment: adding this to the script saved my life [code]
removePlugins: 'floatingspace,resize',[/code]

Answer (score 0):

You are using some extra plugins (like the word counter and the floating toolbar) and probably they haven't been developed to be used in a page with several editors at the same time and in a shared space configuration.

Comment: I am rebuilding the ckeditor removing few plugins. Let me see what happens next. Thanks alfonso..